# Compute $\iint\limits_{R} (x-y) dA$ with a specific change of variables

Tags: calculus

I need to compute $\iint\limits_{R} (x-y) dA$ where $R$ is the region enclosed by $x-y=0,x-y=1,xy=1,xy=2$ using the following change of variables: $v=xy,u=x-y$.

I was not able to express $x$ (or $y$) in terms of $v$ and $u$ (for $x$ I got two roots etc.). So I decided to compute the Jacobian by finding:
$$J^{-1}=\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -1\\ 
y & x
\end{vmatrix}=x+y$$

Thus $J=\frac{1}{x+y}$. However I still can't express $x+y$ in terms of $v$ and $u$.

What can I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: $$
x + y = \sqrt{\left(x -  y\right)^{2} + 4xy} = \sqrt{u^{2} + 4v}
$$
You have to pay attention to the $x + y$ sign.

Answer (score 1):

The given region, without any other indication, is composed of two disconnected components:

[image]

In the two components you should use different solutions to the system
\begin{align}
&x-y=u\\
&xy=v
\end{align}

In the upper-right region, where $x,y>0$, you should use
\begin{align}
&x=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{u^2+4 v}+u\right)\\
&y=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{u^2+4 v}-u\right)
\end{align}

while in the lower-left, where $x,y<0$,

\begin{align}
&x=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{u^2+4 v}+u\right)\\
&y=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{u^2+4 v}-u\right)
\end{align}